# Теоретическое задание о накате обновлений, как поступить?

Tags: вёрстка, кэширование, обновление

Вы обновили вёрстку сайта, но заказчик не видит изменений. Вы посоветовали ему почистить кеш браузера, но не сможете посоветовать этого тысячам других пользователей. Что можно сделать, чтобы избавить всех от необходимости чистить кеш после каждого обновления?